# Error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ReceiptNumber='

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling, ms-access-2010

I am rather new to this and am constantly running across this error. I have found ways to bypass it in the past but cannot so this time even though the code is super simple.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO DonationChangeLog SELECT * FROM DonationReceipts " & "WHERE ReceiptNumber=" & ReceiptNumber
 
End Sub
```

Here is the error:

> Access/Microsoft Visual Basic Error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ReceiptNumber='

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but wrap your entire query in single quotes or put it in parentheses or something. Access is ending the query string before adding `ReceiptNumber` to the end.

Comment: Syntax looks fine to me without throwing in apostrophes or parens. Step debug. Is concatenated ReceiptNumber Null? Is it a number type? If concatenating a textbox, should explicitly qualify: `Me.ReceiptNumber`. The concatenation in front of `WHERE ` is not necessary but shouldn't hurt.

Comment: On debug, ReceiptNumber is reading as Empty. I am basically trying to track any changes that are made to information on a form to a table to log the changes. RecieptNumber is a Long Number Type.

Comment: This has been solved. I deleted all related tables and forms and made them from scratch, so it works now for some reason. Thanks for the suggestions